# error MSB4019: Microsoft.WindowsPhone.v4.5.Overrides.targets" was not found

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, windows-phone-8

I have tried to compile my WindowsPhone 8 project with help of  task under the nant.
(It 's compiled under the VisualStudio2012 Pro without any errors.) But when I execute script via the commandline **I have got the error:**

error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v4.5\Microsoft.WindowsPhone.v4.5.Overrides.targets" was not found

**In vs project:**

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier).$(TargetFrameworkVersion).Overrides.targets" />
```

Is any workaround here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delete this import or change the **$(TargetFrameworkVersion)** onto "**v8.0**" Most probably your project file was created on more older VS2012.

Answer (score 1):

You can update your Visual Studio 2012 and Win8 onto the latest version, and it will work without workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the Visual Studio version to be 2012 in msbuild by using /p:VisualStudioVersion=11.0. See [here](http://sedodream.com/2012/08/19/VisualStudioProjectCompatabilityAndVisualStudioVersion.aspx).